# using sed to remove part of a header line starting with forward slash

Tags: unix, sed, header

I am trying to adjust header lines in a file using sed and I have looked at many previous posts but nothing I've tried based on those so far have helped. So here it goes:
I am using terminal on mac OS, 
I have a file with header lines that look like this: starting with `>`

```
>KeepThis_text_VariableNumbersHere /LotsOFText/Here to get rid of."
```

I want to have:

```
>KeepThis_text_VariableNumbersHere
```

All of the header lines end in ." but there are quotes within the header line as well.

I have tried many variations using sed, here are a few:

```
 sed -e 's/^\/*.*//' input.file > output.file  #this removed everything
```

or

```
 sed -e 's/^\/*.*"//' input.file > output.file #this kept non-header
```

lines, which is good, but got rid of entire header line

```
sed -e 's/>KeepThis_Text_*.* *.*”/>KeepThis_Text_*.*\//' input.file > output.file #This did not change anything
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `cut -d/ -f1` gives you the first part, but what do you mean with header lines? Only the first line in a file or all lines starting with a `>` and ending with a `.`? Or must they also have 2 slashes? `> I am a header line with two // and a dot.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change 1st line, consider *addressing* your command (`s///`):

```
sed -re '1s/\/\w+//g'
```

or addressing all lines beginning with `>`:

```
sed -re '/^>/s/\/\w+//g'
```

or if you want to drop everything from `/` to end of line:

```
sed -re '/^>/s/\/.*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only keep the part that precedes the forward slash, then the following will do:

```
sed -e 's-/.*--'
```

The separators for the command are not limited to `/`, it is just a convention. Here, I used `-` as command separators. The command is then: replace anything following a slash until the end of line with empty text.

Comment: Hooray, this worked perfectly, thank you so much! I knew I had to be close but was getting messed up using all the forward slashes, good to know for future work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use capture everything starting from `>` including everything before space followed by a `/` in a capturing group. The keep only the capturing group and throw away the remaining text, like this:

```
sed 's/\(>[^\/]\+\) .*/\1/' input.txt
```

It looks more clean using extended regular expression, using the `-r` option:

```
sed -r 's/(>[^\/]+) .*/\1/' input.txt
```

I'm not sure if *header line* means for you *the first line*. If you really mean the *first line*, limit the `s` command to the first line like this:

```
sed -r '1s/(>[^/]+) .*/\1/' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what you did here, I was able to get it working with the first response above, but your post has some helpful info for future use with sed!

Comment: @Carla Btw, If you like the *first response above*, then you need to accept it. This is done by clicking the check mark right beside that answer.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk -F/ 'NR==1{print $1;next}1' file
```

modifies first line only, prints everything up to `/`.